# Late Binding: Expecting error but not getting it

Tags: vb.net

I wrote the below code to understand Late Binding with Option Strict ON. With OPTION STRICT ON, I was expecting an error in the statement: `o = New Car()`. But not getting any error. Isn't that strange? Its clearly mentioned in the MSDN documentation on Option Strict that when ON it prevents late binding - gives a compile time error. So what is happening here....can someone pls help?

```
Option Strict On
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim o As Object
        o = New Car() 'Expecting error here but not getting
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Class Car
    Public Property Make As String
    Public Property price As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: I don't think so.  Car is a descendant of Object.  Think it's more the other way around.  something like declaring o as a car, then trying to assign an object to it

Comment: This: `Dim o As Object = New Car()` is not Late Binding, it's an assignment. This is : `o.Make = "Something"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing at all wrong or inappropriate about assigning an object of a derived type to a variable of a base type. That's exactly what allows for polymorphism, which is a cornerstone of OOP. What constitutes late binding is trying to access a member of the derived type via a reference of the base type.

The compiler only knows the type of the reference, so it only knows about members of that type. If you try to access a member that doesn't belong to that base type type then the compiler cannot confirm that that access is valid. Type-checking must be deferred until run time, when the type of the object is determined and it is confirmed whether that member actually exists.

Early binding is when the the existence of a member on a type is confirmed at compile time, while late binding is when it's done at run time. If there is no member access then there is no binding at all to be early or late.

```vb
Dim c As New Car
Dim o As Object = New Car

c.Make = "Ford" 'Early binding
o.Price = 20000 'Late binding
```

In the code above, the setting of the `Make` property is early-bound because `Make` is a member of the type of `c`. On the other hand, the setting of `Price` is late-bound because `Price` is not a member of the type of `o` so confirmation that the object has such a member must be deferred until run time.

Comment: Hi..had a follow up question. Like we can do explicit narrowing conversion with Option Strict ON, is there a way to perform Late Binding also with Option Strict ON?

Comment: @Sougata, the point of `Option Strict On` is to disallow implicit narrowing conversions and late-binding, so no. You should pretty much always have `Option Strict On` at the project level. Set it in the VS options to make that the default. If you require late binding, set `Option Strict Off` at the file level in only those files that require it, using partial classes to keep the code in those files to an absolute minimum.

Comment: Thanks again for your help